# SetFocusedRowCellValue doesn't update underlying datasource

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have to set current row's ACTIVE field to 1 when user press Shift-Delete. I have setup KeyDown and CustomRowFilter events for GridView but I can't set the ACTIVE field to 1 with SetFocusedRowCellValue and SetRowCellValue methods.

```
    private void gvMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if ((e.Shift == true) && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete))
                {
                    GridView gvTmp = sender as GridView;
                    //gvTmp.SetFocusedRowCellValue("ACTIVE", 1); //DOES NOTHING
                    //gvTmp.SetRowCellValue(gvTmp.FocusedRowHandle, "ACTIVE", 1); //DOES NOTHING
                    //gvMain.SetRowCellValue(gvMain.FocusedRowHandle, "ACTIVE", 1); //DOES NOTHING
                    //gvMain.SetFocusedRowCellValue("ACTIVE", 1); //DOES NOTHING
                    dtMain.Rows[gvTmp.GetDataSourceRowIndex(gvTmp.FocusedRowHandle)]["ACTIVE"] = 1; //OK
                    gvMain.RefreshData();
                    }
            }
```

How can I set current row's ACTIVE field to 1 with GridView methods? I don't like to set values directly to datatable.

Comment: I have noticed that you are calling the SetFocusedRowCellValue/SetRowCellValue method for **gvTmp** while you are accessing a focused row handle by using the **gvMain**.FocusedRowHandle property. It is likely that **gvTmp** and **gvMain** are different views. If you are working in the [Master-Detail mode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3473/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Master-Detail/Master-Detail-Relationships) and you need to access a detail view, use the GridControl.FocusedView property or the GridView.GetDetailView method (this method is called from a master view).

Comment: @Svetlana I don't use master-detail relationship. gvTmp is just temporary GridView which I get from KeyPress sender parameter. I've updated code on the question. Thanks for clearance but it still doesn't update.

Comment: Either line of your code is correct and works in a simple test project. The problem is somewhere else. Try to create a simple runnable project and check whether or not you can reproduce the problem by copying your existing code into a small project. This can give you a clue.